# Solution of a separable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(y + \sin y)\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x + x^3$

Certainly seems straight forward.  When I separate I get:

$(y+ \sin y) dy = (x + x^3) dx$

Easy to integrate both sides

So, then I get $\frac12 y^2 -\cos (y) = \frac14 x^4 + \frac12 x^2 +C$.

At this point I feel kinda stuck.  Aren't I now suppose to solve for $y(x)$?

Would I do this as a quadratic in y, with the x terms being constant?
I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: I thinkt there is no explicit solution. You can only state an implicit solution for this ODE.

Comment: How do I know when there is only an implicit solution?

Comment: I think there are formal ways to see that, but it is very unlikely that you will be able to solve for $y$ in this case. In this case I suspect that there is no explicit solution because in general it is not possible so solve mixed expressions with polynomials and trigonometric functions. You could also try computer algebra systems like maple or mathematica and tell them to solve for $y$. If they cant do it, it is very likely that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac12 y^2 -\cos (y) = \frac14 x^4 + \frac12 x^2 +C$$.

Solving for $x$ :
$$x=\pm \sqrt{-1\pm \sqrt{2y^2-4\cos(y)+1-4C}}$$
This is the solution of the ODE expressed on the form of the function $x(y)$.

$y(x)$ is the inverse function(s), formally with  any dummy variable $t$ :
$$y(t)=\arg\left(\pm \sqrt{-1\pm \sqrt{2t^2-4\cos(t)+1-4C}}\right)$$
$y(x)$ is this function for $t=x$.

There is no simpler closed form for this function.